# Use for loop in find exec

Tags: bash, find

```
 -> find  .. -name bin  -exec  for file in {}/* ; do echo $file ; done  \;

   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

What is the proper syntax for this command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use multiple statements, such as a `for`-loop, as the argument to `-exec`, one needs to invoke a shell, such as `bash`, explicitly:

```
find .. -name bin -exec bash -c 'for file in "$1"/* ; do echo "$file" ; done' none {}  \;
```

This is safe even for filenames that contain spaces or other hostile characters.

#### How `bash -c` works

One can invoke bash with a command of the form:

```
bash -c some_complex_commands arg0 arg1 arg2 ...
```

In this case, bash will execute whatever is in the string `some_complex_commands`.  Those commands can make use of the usual shell *positional parameters*.  The first argument after command, `arg0` above, is assigned to `$0`, the second to `$1`, the third to `$2`, etc.

When one executes a normal shell script, `$0` is the name of the script and `$1` is the first argument that appears on the command line.  In keeping with that tradition, the `bash -c` command was written to assign the file name, `{}` in find's notation, to `$1`.  Since this script does not have a sensible name, `none` is assigned as a placeholder to `$0`.

Comment: ya man bash those hostile characters

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got things reversed from what you want. Try this:

```
for f in `find .. -name bin`
do
echo $f
done
```

Comment: Nope . I want to know the syntax for what I placed in the original question .

Comment: @JamesAndino There is no need to loop inside `find` therefore it outputs founded elements like loop by itself

Comment: Your answer doesn’t even do _anything_ except for printing a bunch of blank lines — `$file` is never set to anything.  Perhaps you don’t understand what James was trying to do.

Comment: Correct on both counts, though I've just fixed the answer to address the first issue you noted. I still don't understand why he's looping inside the find's exec instead of looping over the entire output, but that may be because he never explained that.

Comment: I'm finding a set of folders then looping through the collection of commands in those bins .  The problem with your answer is that if there are new line characters ( maybe spaces tabs etc I always forget ) the script will die a fiery death . Normally not a problem looping your own bin but I'll look for sub folders with a user chosen name and kaboom goes trash puter

Comment: @Scott if you read the question, the question just echos, so the question is about what a principle is re syntax. And this answer replies to that.

Comment: @barlop:  And if you read everything relevant, your level of understanding might increase.

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate the output of your pseudo-code there with `find` primitives as is:

```
find .. -path \*/bin/\* ! -name .\*
```

...which should print only files/dirs with names that do not begin with a . and which are rooted at some level both in the parent directory, and, at some greater degree, in a dir named `/bin`.

In general I can think of all kinds of practical purposes for looping in a `find -exec` child process, but not a one in which I could consider it practical to do shelld glob on an argument passed by `find`. To do the same thing your pseudo-code does with `printf` - because its use can guarantee literal translation of arguments to output - you might do...

```
find .. -type d -name bin -exec sh -c '
    printf %s\\n "$0/"*' {} \;
```

...which does the printing and the globbing without the `for` loop. One difference between this and your example command, though, is that without the `-type d` specification and type of result matching the name `bin` will be `echo`d - and so you're highly likely to see a lot of `bin/*` being written to stdout. Of course, even w/ `-type d`, there's no guarantee that the `*` will resolve - an empty directory or one containing only `.`files will render no matches and so you might see it anyway.

Note also that the example pseudo code, because it uses the `{} \;` primitives might be a lot slower than some other ways. We'll try the `printf` thing again like:

```
find .. -type d -name bin -exec sh -c '
    for d do printf %s\\n "$d/"*; done' -- {} +
```

...which still risks the empty glob case but instead of `-exec`ing a shell per match, it rather gathers as many arguments as it might reasonably pass off to another process at exec time and passes the lot to `sh` in `"$@"` its positional parameter array - which we can loop over with `for d do printf...`.

Now if you wanted to do something other than just print results - which is what I would typically consider useful about looping in an `-exec` statement - you can fallback to the earlier `-path` example and combine it with `-exec` like...

```
find .. -path \*/bin/\* -exec sh -c '
    for arg do : something with "$arg"
done' -- {} +
```

Comment: This is very useful . While waiting for an answer I actually figured to use globstar . I was actually going to ask about adapting my find command to find more specifically the files in bin and not just the bins to recurse .

Comment: @JamesAndino - You can do it without recursion: `find .. -path '*/bin/*' ! -name . -prune ! -type d` which should print only files other than type directory which reside in a directory named `../(*/)*bin`.