# Copy folders to another set of directories, only if folders already exist

Tags: recursive

I want to copy (overwrite) folders from one directory to another set of directories, only if the folders in directory1 exist in directory2.

For example, I have stored some folders in my home directory:

```
home
    |admin
        |updates
            |package1
            |package2
            |package3
```

I also have another folder with builds of an app:

```
home
    |builds
        |build1
            |packages
                |package1
                |package2
                |package3
        |build2
            |packages
                |package1
                |package3
        |build3
            |rev1
                |packages
                    |package1
            |rev2
                |packages
                    |package2
```

I want the 'package1', 'package2', 'package3' folders found in '/home/updates/package' directory to be copied over to the 'packages' folders found recursively in '/home/builds' directory, but only if the folders already exist.

So in the example above, 'package1'/'package2'/'package3' would be copied into '/home/builds/build1/packages'. Only 'package1' would be copied into '/home/builds/build3/rev1/packages' ('package2'/'package3' would not because it doesn't exist there).

In addition, 'build1'/'build2'/'build3' may have different owner/group permissions so I would like to retain the relative target directory's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p test/updates/pack1
...
mkdir -p test/builds/builds1/packages/pack3
...
touch test/updates/pack1/f1-1
...
```

run this command

```
find test/builds -type d  -name packages -exec bash -c 'for pk in "$1"/pack* ; do cp -r test/updates/"${pk##*/}" $1 ; done' none {} \;
```

- 'find' will [search recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard) for "packages" directories.
- '-exec bash -c' will run a [batch with the result of 'find'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193869/use-for-loop-in-find-exec).
- The bash 'for' loop will search for existing "packX" in the destination
  and copy them from source (using [param. extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011233/for-files-in-directory-only-echo-filename-no-path)) to the destination.

Greetings

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome! I just need to find a way to preserve the target permissions; might just store them at the beginning of the script and then reapply them after the files are copied over. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in package1 package2 package3; do find /home/ -name $i -type d -not -path "/home/admin/updates/$i" -exec cp /home/admin/updates/$i/* {} \;; done
```

- `for i in package1 package2 package3; ... ; done` - iterate through the names of the folders
- `find /home/ -name $i -type d` - recursively find all the folders with said names in the /home/ directory
- `-not -path "/home/admin/updates/$i"` - exclude from find results the original directory
- `-exec cp /home/admin/updates/$i/* {} \;` - execute the command - copy files from original folder to found folder